# Django send mail from docker container

Tags: django, email, docker

I have a Django application and when I run it locally it all works fine. But in production that runs in a docker container it can not send mail anymore I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/training/schema.py", line 167, in mutate
   fail_silently=False,
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 60, in send_mail
   return mail.send()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 294, in send
   return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
   new_conn_created = self.open()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 63, in open
   self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
  (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
  self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
  self.source_address)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
  raise err
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I am using these settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'me@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the Docker container have the mail port open?

Comment: What port would this be?

Comment: It's there in your settings: `EMAIL_PORT = 587`

Comment: Appertently it had nothing to do with the docker or the django. I did not have the mail port openend on the server that was hosting the site.

Answer (score 0):

I would check connectivity status to the destination host smtp.gmail.com at port 587 from your production host.